# How can I make my program recognize tabs and turn them into normal spaces?

Tags: c

I am currently in the process of learning/ re-learning C. I had some trouble learning it last year in school. I am using a book and one of the exercises is asking to get excessive spaces and turn them into just one space. The problem is that I can't make it recognize tabs. I have looked for some on here already but they all deal with arrays. I can't use arrays. This is what I have so far.

```
int main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            putchar(c);
            for (c = getchar(); c == ' '; c = getchar())
                ;
        }
        else if (c == '\t')
            putchar(' ');
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

So basically, the code starts off with getting a char value and putting it into "c". then while c is not EOF, if c equals the ASCII value of SPACE it is going to output it and enter a for loop. The for loop tests for additional spaces. c equals the following char and while c equals the ASCII value of SPACE, it the for loop will do nothing and it will iterate until all additional spaces are gone. The if statement works perfectly by the way.

Then I go into an else if which I am certain is wrong but it's my latest attempt. So for this I said else if c equals the ASCII value of tab (is that a thing? If not that might be what my error is) put down a space by using putchar(' '). I feel like that command might be wrong as well. After that statement it then exits the conditional, puts out the value then c now equals a new char and the loop continues.

Thanks!

EDIT: So right after posting this I realized, at least I think, my error is the putchar(c) at the bottom which is still printing out the tab regardless? Although I am still not sure how to approach the problem. One more thing is that these are the only commands I can use. The book still assumes I don't know how arrays and such work in C yet.

Comment: Your `for (c = getchar(); c == ' '; c = getchar())` is fishy. Look at the second `c = getchar()`.

Comment: I suggest you flow-chart and then desk-check your program.

Comment: Think of it this way - if `c` is a space, do one thing, *else if* `c` is a tab, do another thing, *else* do some third thing.

Comment: Have you learned the `||` operator?  I would be using `if if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')` at some point.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Or [`isspace`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace)

Answer (score 0):

Although its a bit unclear on how subsequent spaces/tabs are to be handled, consider simply saving the previous character.

```
int previous = EOF;
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetchar()) != EOF) {
  if (ch == '\t') {  // or if (isblank(ch)) ...
    ch = ' '; 
  }
  if (previous != ' ') {
    putchar(ch);
  }
  previous = ch;
}
```

Comment: I see. The for loop just has a ; in it. On my actual code it's underneath the for idk why it is appearing next to it here. Just noticed that actually.  but basically it does nothing for every additional time that c is a space.

Comment: That is just a way to execute the loop and nothing else, like `for (...) {}`, which is equivalent to `for (...);`, the latter is just less readable.